# Emulation of an active FTP connection using BSD Sockets

Tags: c, sockets, network-programming

I am new to socket progamming and I am trying to implement a stripped down FTP like program. 
It uses two TCP connections, one as a control connection and other as a data connection. The problem is that I do not know how to use the sever to connect to the client's N+1 port using its port 20. Please refer [here](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html#actexample), to fund out more.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To create the active mode data connection, you:

- Find the local address of the control connection with `getsockname()`;
- modify this address by changing the port number to 20;
- create another socket with `socket()`;
- bind the new socket to the port 20 address created with `bind()`;
- connect the socket to the client's address/port with `connect()`.

Note that the `bind()` will likely fail if your daemon is not running as root, because binding a low port number is a privileged operation.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably go through [FTP RFC 959](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc959.txt) to get all the details.
Client needs to share data port to the server if it wants server to initiate data connection.